# Perform excel macro on a csv file from C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv, xlsm

I need to perform an existing Excel Macro (written in VB, can be copied from Excel using the Macro editor) on an existing csv file using C#. I already have working code that I can use to perform the Macro on an xlsm file, which looks like this:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace MacroBuddy
{
    public class test
    {
        public static void go_Macro()
        {
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            //create new Excel application instance
            Excel.Application oExcel = new Excel.Application();

            oExcel.Visible = true;

            Excel.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
            Excel._Workbook oBook = null;

            string path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.csv";

            //open file located at path
            oBook = oBooks.Open(path, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

            //run Macro by referencing file and the name of the Macro
            RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[] { "test.xlsm!TestMacro" });

            //save and close workbook
            oBook.Save();
            oBook.Close(false, oMissing, oMissing);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook);
            oBook = null;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks);
            oBooks = null;
            oExcel.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
            oExcel = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private static void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
        { oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oApp, oRunArgs); }

        static void Main()
        { go_Macro(); }
    }
}
```

However, it does not work if the file specified is a csv file. So I need help make similar code work on a csv file, or an automated process to convert the csv file to an xlsm file from C#.

Also, it would be helpful to be able to take the VB macro code as a string and be able to run a macro using a method that would take the string as an argument or some similar process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing to a csv in the first place, I decided to write to an .xlsx file with multiple sheets using something like this:

```
public class test
{
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    public test()
    {
        Excel.Application XL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook WB = XL.Workbooks.Add(missing);
        Excel.Worksheet Sheet = WB.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
        oSheet.Name = "First sheet";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Written on first sheet";
        Excel.Worksheet Sheet2 = WB.Sheets.Add(missing, missing, 1, missing) 
                    as Excel.Worksheet;
        Sheet2.Name = "Second sheet";
        Sheet2.Cells[1, 1] = "Written on second sheet";
        string fileName = @"C:\temp\SoSample.xlsx";
        oWB.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
            missing, missing, missing, missing,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        oWB.Close(missing, missing, missing);
        oXL.UserControl = true;
        oXL.Quit();
    }
}
```

And I then created the with the workbook with the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
         Excel.Application oExcel;
         Excel.Workbook oBook;
         VBIDE.VBComponent oModule;
         Office.CommandBar oCommandBar;
         Office.CommandBarButton oCommandBarButton;
         String sCode;
         Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
         // Create an instance of Excel.
         oExcel = new Excel.Application();

         // Add a workbook.
         oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.xlsm");

         // Create a new VBA code module.
         oModule = oBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

         sCode =
         //paste in your macro here, with each line followed by a new line
         "Sub TestMacro()\r\n" +
         "Columns(\"D:D\").Select\r\n" +
         "Selection.Copy\r\n" +
         "Columns(\"F:F\").Select\r\n" +
         "ActiveSheet.Paste\r\n" +
         "Application.CutCopyMode = False\r\n" +
         "ActiveSheet.Range(\"$F$1:$F$542\").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo\r\n" +
         "Range(\"F1\").Select\r\n" +
         "ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = \"Unique Query\"\r\n" +
         "Range(\"F2\").Select\r\n" +
         "End Sub";
         // Add the VBA macro to the new code module.
         oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);



         // Make Excel visible to the user.
         oExcel.Visible = true;
         // Set the UserControl property so Excel won't shut down.
         oExcel.UserControl = true;

         // Release the variables.
         oModule = null;
         oBook = null;
         oExcel = null;             
         // Collect garbage.
         GC.Collect();
}
```

I was then able to run the macro just created with the code I originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following 2 links will help u open csv File and then save it in excel format.
so after that u open the excel file and perform your task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9838808.aspx (Open CSV)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e33e36.aspx (Save excel).